# Отправка JSON на сервер и добавление в БД

Tags: php, java, mysql

Клиент (Java). Выполняется jar на компьютере

```
static void addToBd(String name, String year, String quality, String genre, String duration, String ozvuchka, String country, String cast, String producer, String description, String download, String art, String screenshots){
    try
    {
        String jsonResponse;

        URL url = new URL("http://<некий адрес>/<некий скрипт>.php?");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        JSONObject film = new JSONObject();
        film.put("name", name);
        film.put("year", year);
        film.put("quality", quality);
        film.put("genre", genre);
        film.put("duration", duration);
        film.put("ozvuchka", ozvuchka);
        film.put("country", country);
        film.put("cast", cast);
        film.put("producer", producer);
        film.put("description", description);
        film.put("download", download);
        film.put("art", art);
        film.put("screenshots", screenshots);
        String strJsonBody = "json="+film.toString();
        System.out.println("strJsonBody: " + strJsonBody);

        byte[] sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
        con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(sendBytes);

        int httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

        if (httpResponse >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
            && httpResponse < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
            scanner.close();
        }
        else
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
            jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
            scanner.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Response: " + jsonResponse);

    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Сервер

```
<?php
 $servername = ":)";
 $username = ":)";
 $password = ":)"; 
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
 $conn -> query("USE admin_filmsanwap");
 $conn->set_charset("utf8");
 if ($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$data = $_POST['json'];
$result = json_decode($data);

$name = $result->name;
    $year = $result->year;
    $quality = $result->quality;
    $genre = $result->genre;
    $duration = $result->duration;
    $ozvuchka = $result->ozvuchka;
    $country = $result->country;
    $cast = $result->cast;
    $producer = $result->producer;
    $description = $result->description;
    $download = $result->download;
    $art = $result->art;
    $screenshots = $result->screenshots;
$insert = "INSERT INTO `admin_filmsanwap`.`films` (`name`,`year`,`quality`,`genre`,`duration`,`ozvuchka`,`country`,`cast`,`producer`,`description`,`download`,`art`,`screenshots`) VALUES ('$name', '$year', '$quality', '$genre', '$duration', '$ozvuchka', '$country', '$cast', '$producer', '$description', '$download', '$art', '$screenshots');";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $insert)){
    echo 'success';
    } 
else {
if ($conn->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 
  }
  ?>
```

Ответ от сервера

```
strJsonBody: json={"name":"t","year":"t","quality":"t","genre":"t","duration":"t","ozvuchka":"t","country":"t","cast":"t","producer":"t","description":"t","download":"t","art":"t","screenshots":"t"}
httpResponse: 200
Response: success
```

Почему в БД добавляется запись с пустыми колонками? Где ошибка? Будет ли работать UTF-8?

Comment: После `echo 'success';` добавьте `var_dump($result);` и посмотрите ответ сервера после этого.

Comment: @Visman, NULL :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем Вам смешивать два формата?

Вы сообщаете в запросе что отсылаете данные в формате `application/json`, а шлёте вы их в формате `multipart/form-data`.

Замените в Java-клиенте тело запроса

```
String strJsonBody = "json="+film.toString();
```

на

```
String strJsonBody = film.toString();
```

И в php его получение:
замените:

```
$data = $_POST['json'];
$result = json_decode($data);
```

на следующие строки:

```
$data  = file_get_contents("php://input");
$result = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался :D

Comment: @Flippy, не за что ;-) Удачного дня!